# Delete config conformance pack from one of the account under organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I created delegated administrator and deployed config rule conformance pack watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDuUyxdxez8 and using management account using cli I created delegated admin to my Security account. Now I want to remove the conformance pack from another account but it is giving me the error and not able to delete it.